# MySQL Percentage Rank without the function

Tags: mysql, sql, percentile

I am forced to create a percent rank on a number of columns in a database table and I am really struggling with this.  Usually I would use the PERCENT_RANK function but I am forced to use conventional query as our MySQL version doesn't offer that function.

I have a table that contains the columns:

```
UID  Total-Orders-Placed Last-Order-Date-Diff
12884           8                351
10985           11               106
30613           3                43
30820           2                134
23421           9                76
```

I would like to add 2 ranking columns as below:

```
UID  Total-Orders-Placed Last-Order-Date-Diff    rec_rank   freq_rank
12884           8                351                0.34      0.86
10985           11               106                0.64      0.91
30613           3                43                 0.85      0.59
30820           2                134                0.57      0.40
23421           9                76                 0.77      0.88
```

In reality I have thousands of rows and additional columns but that's the gist.  I have been able to do it perfectly in Excel but I am really struggling to convert into Query/Views in our MySQL Database so our data can be viewed realtime.

I have tried PERCENT_RANK() but as I mention above this function isn't available to us.

I have tried the queries discussed here without too much success yet: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-ranking-without-self-join

Any help writing the code or to give me a better understanding of it would really help.

Comment: Upgrade to MySQL 8+?

Comment: Not possible tediously :(  We use Amazon Aurora MySQL 5.6.10 I think, going to check now.

Comment: Do you mean this [PERCENT_RANK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_percent-rank) function? This function calculates percentages (values between 0 and 1), so please explain how this function could be related to your example while your example has integers 1,2,...5?

Comment: thanks @krokodilko I did it without thinking as in the excel sheet we turn convert it into a % out of 100.  The data above is fake to try and represent much more complicated data.  But ultimately you are right I am after the value between 0 and 1 created from PERCENT_RANK.

Comment: OK, then please explain which input fields (`Total-Orders-Placed`, `Last-Order-Date-Diff`) are taken to calculate each output values (`Freq-Rank` +`Rec-Rank`) - I am trying to reverse engeenier these formulas looking at numbers from your example, but without success.

Comment: Sorry about this - I had tried to take an example piece of data from my data set but naturally I can't provide it all.  I thought I could mimic but obviously failed miseraly.  Ultimately the sheet has 14390 rows, the original post has been edited to take 5 random entries from these out.  The recency rank (rec_rank) is taken from "last-order-date-diff" column and the frequency rank (freq_rank) is taken from the "total-orders-placed" column.  Without my entire sheet is this too complicated.  I actually have 5 other rank fields :(... Is there anything I should read to help?